# Trying to find the 'max files per directory' figure for an OCFS2/LVM volume

Tags: lvm, ocfs2

I have a bunch of RHEL/OEL Apache VMs (on ESX 3.5) hardware load-balanced into a little http file farm. I need to expand the dataset they're serving from 1TB to 10TB and although I can use OCFS2 and LVM to make it actually work I'm a bit worried about running into any limitations that I'm currently aware of. In particular I'm worried about LUN sizes that LVM is happy to deal with and also the number of files OCFS2 will support in a directory and also per volume. I've looked around in the obvious places but does anyone have any practical experience of this area?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly, there is no such limit. The index is supposed to handle any number of files up to the maximum available blocks, even if they are all in the root.

However, if I remember correctly, the allocation bitmap is fixed to 2^20 bytes. So a single OCFS2 filesystem can only contain 8,388,608 files.

The maximum volume size for OCFS2 is 16 TiB on 32-bit and 4 PiB on 64-bit platforms.

The maximum logical volume size for LVM2 is 16 TiB on 32-bit platforms, and 8 EiB on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Don't mention it, sorry you had to wait two months for an answer.